# Sed/awk - How to remove newline characters between start pattern and end pattern.

Tags: linux, awk, sed

Example logs:

```
2018-01-01 11:30:22 xxx Parsing xxx
2018-01-01 11:30:23 driver queryId=<xxx> Parsing command: select *
from table 
limit 10
2018-01-01 11:30:25 Parsing completed 
2018-01-01 11:30:28 xxxxxx
2018-01-01 11:30:40 driver queryId=<xxx> Parsing command: select * from table group by column
2018-01-01 11:30:45 Parsing completed 
2018-01-01 11:30:51 xxxxxx
2018-01-01 11:30:52 xxx Parsing xxx
2018-01-01 11:30:54 driver queryId=<xxx> Parsing command: select 

*
from table 

order by column

limit 20
2018-01-01 11:30:56 Parsing completed 
2018-01-01 11:30:59 xxxxxx
```

I want to remove newlines between "Parsing command:" and the "2018" matching pattern and output should contain the words only matching the pattern.

Example parsing:

```
2018-01-01 11:30:54 driver queryId=<xxx> Parsing command: select 

*
from table 

order by column

limit 20
2018-01-01 11:30:56 Parsing completed
```

Output of the above example should be,

```
select * from table order by column limit 20
```

Comment: should it process only queries which have newlines ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty short solution using perl instead of sed/awk:

```
perl -ne 's/\n/ /; print +(s/^.*Parsing command: // .. /^2018/ or next) =~ /E/ ? "\n" : $_' input.log
```

The idea:

We loop over the input lines (`-n`). For each line we execute code (`-e ...`):

- First we replace the newline by a space (`s/\n/ /`).
- Then we check a `COND1 .. COND2` condition, which is true for all lines in the range between COND1 and COND2.
- Our first condition is the substitution `s/^.*Parsing command: //`, which is true if it managed to remove some prefix of the input line ending with `Parsing command:`. This is the beginning of our range.
- Our second condition is the match `/^2018/`, which is true if the input line starts with `2018`. This is the end of our range.
- If this check fails, we just skip to the next input line (`... or next`). For the rest of the code we're only considering lines within the range.
- The value returned by `..` is a sequence number. The last line in the range has `E0` appended to it. We check for `/E/` to exclude the last line of the range (the one starting with `2018`), because we don't want to print it.
- If we're at the last line, we just output a newline (`"\n"`), otherwise we print the line (with the final newline converted to space from the first substitution).

Comment: @melpomene Nice, But you could consider the pattern `Parsing completed` for your second condition, which I feel is more authoritative. Anyways  nice and great explanation `:+)`

Answer (score 1):

`sed` could also be used , though it looks a bit scary <kbd>:-/</kbd>

```
sed -nE '/Parsing command:/{
s/^.*Parsing command://;:l1;N;/Parsing completed[[:blank:]]*$/!bl1;
s/2018-.*Parsing completed[[:blank:]]*$//;
s/\n/ /g;s/^[[:blank:]]*//;s/[[:blank:]]+/ /gp}' logfile
```

---

<sup>Note the last two substitutions are for some fine-grained formatting and the `p` flag with last `s` takes care of printing.</sup>

---

**Output**

```
select * from table limit 10 
select * from table group by column 
select * from table order by column limit 20
```

All good <kbd>:-)</kbd>

---

<sup>**Recommended reading :** `sed` [branching](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Branching-and-flow-control.html#Branching-and-Flow-Control) statements.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '/Parsing command:/{ f=1; sub(/.*Parsing command: /,""); q=$0; next }
     f && /^2018/{ gsub(/[[:space:]]{2,}/, " ", q); print q; f=0 }
     NF && f{ q=q" "$0 }' logfile
```

The output:

```
select * from table limit 10
select * from table group by column
select * from table order by column limit 20
```

Comment: May be one more `sed` to suppress the extra spaces. `:-)`

Comment: @sjsam, `Awk` has enough power to reach that by oneself )) Done

Comment: Well formatted ! You may consider the pattern `/Parsing completed[[:blank:]]*$/` instead of `^2018` because the former is more authoritative. Just a suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

**sed script**: file `extractcommand.sed`:

```
#!/usr/bin/sed -f
/Parsing command:/!{d;b}          # delete+continue if 'Parsing command' not found
:a                                # if found, then start a loop with label (a)
  s/.*Parsing command:\s*//       #   delete that 'Parsing command'
  /Parsing completed/{            #   if found 'Parsing completed'
    s:\n[^\n]*Parsing completed:: #     then delete that 'Parsing completed'
    s:\n: :g                      #     change all \n to space
    s:  *: :g                     #     remove all extra spaces (optional)
    b                             #     break the loop (and print as default)
  }                               #
  N                               #   load another line into buffer
  ba                              #   loop to label (a)
```

Test:

```
$ ./extractcommand.sed <sample.log 
select * from table limit 10 
select * from table group by column 
select * from table order by column limit 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple. Given your first posted input file, using GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -F'Parsing command: ' -v RS='[^\n]+Parsing completed' 'RT{gsub(/\s+/," ",$NF); print $NF}' file
select * from table limit 10
select * from table group by column
select * from table order by column limit 20
```

or with any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/Parsing completed/ {
    gsub(/ +/," ",buf)
    sub(/.*Parsing command: /,"",buf)
    print buf
    buf = ""
}
{ buf = buf " " $0 }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
select * from table limit 10
select * from table group by column
select * from table order by column limit 20
```